# Gson/php call gives IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to read a webservice into my Android app, but I get a

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1

For what I understand this happens when JSON arrays have names, but I don't understand why this happens to my JSON, which looks like this:

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "nombre": "Name1",
    "telefono": "5529964",
    "correo": "mail@hotmail.com"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "nombre": "Name2",
    "telefono": "5435432",
    "correo": ""
}
```

]

For context, this is how I call gson:

```
public List<Estudiante> leerFlujoJson(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    // Nueva instancia de la clase Gson
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
    reader.setLenient(true);
    List<Estudiante> estudiantes = new ArrayList<>();

    // Iniciar el array
    reader.beginArray();

    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        // Lectura de objetos
        Estudiante estudiante = gson.fromJson(reader, Estudiante.class);
        estudiantes.add(estudiante);
    }


    reader.endArray();
    reader.close();
    return estudiantes;
}
```

Comment: I doubt that the json you get looks like that. Gson expects a `[` to begin an array but sees a string which most likely means a `"`. Is the data you get escaped or otherwise wrapped in something? Or do you maybe get an error page instead of the json?

Comment: That's how my JSON looks seen from my browser, however when I change my php file to return json_encoded($result), it gives the `"json"` with the quotation marks you mentioned. I'll add my php method.

Comment: look at the page source in the browser. that's most likely what your program sees

Comment: I see. It looks like the JSON is inside a `<pre>` HTML tag which somehow adds the quotation marks. However I don't have any clue how it got there.

Comment: I've never done php but maybe something in http://www.sitepoint.com/best-practices-rest-api-scratch-introduction/ gives you an idea how to write the sever  side code to return json instead of html

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep looking!